# Overriding methods and inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I am trying to complete a code with Parent class Pet, and subclasses Dog and Cat. The Pet class defines the variables and the subclasses calculate how much of each drug (carprofen and acepromazine) each pet can safely intake.

I am having problems invoking the carprofen and acepromazine methods in the main method. I don't know what I did wrong.

It returns the carprofen and acepromazine values always as 0.0

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pet {
    String kind;
    double weight;
    double atotalAmount;
    double ctotalAmount;

    public Pet(String startKind, double startWeight) {
        kind = startKind;
        weight = startWeight;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String newValue) {
        kind = newValue;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double newValue) {
        weight = newValue;
    }

    public double calcCarprofen(double weight) {
        return ctotalAmount;
    }

    public double calcAcepromazine(double weight) {
        return atotalAmount;
    }
}

class Cat extends Pet {
    public Cat(String startKind, double startWeight) {
        super(startKind, startWeight);
    }

    public double calcCarprofen(double weight) {
        double c = 12.0;
        double ccatdose = .25;
        double ctotalAmount = (((weight) / (2.2)) * ((ccatdose) / (c)));
        return ctotalAmount;
    }

    public double calcAcepromazine(double weight) {
        double a = 10.0;
        double acatdose = .002;
        double atotalAmount= (((weight) / (2.2)) * ((acatdose) / (a)));
        return atotalAmount;
    }
}

class Dog extends Pet {
    public Dog(String startKind, double startWeight) {
        super(startKind, startWeight);
    }

    public double calcCarprofen(double weight) {
        double c = 12.0;
        double cdogdose = .5;
        double ctotalAmount = 0.0;
        ctotalAmount = (((weight) / (2.2)) * ((cdogdose) / (c)));
        return ctotalAmount;
    }

    public double calcAzepromazine(double weight) {
        double a = 10.0;
        double adogdose = .03;
        double atotalAmount = 0.0;
        atotalAmount = (((weight) / (2.2)) * ((adogdose) / (a)));
        return atotalAmount;
    }
}

public class Ch7Ex8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double startWeight;
        String startKind;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Is this a cat or dog?: ");
        startKind = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the pet's weight: ");
        startWeight = keyboard.nextDouble();

        Cat usersCat = new Cat(startKind, startWeight);
        Dog usersDog = new Dog(startKind, startWeight);

        double catcdose = usersCat.calcCarprofen( double weight);
        double catadose = usersCat.calcAcepromazine( double weight);
        double dogcdose = usersDog.calcCarprofen( double weight);
        double dogadose = usersDog.calcAcepromazine( double weight);
        System.out.println("The total cat carprofen dose is: " + catcdose);
        System.out.println("The total cat acepromazine dose is: " + catadose);
        System.out.println("The total dog carprofen dose is: " + dogcdose);
        System.out.println("The total dog acepromazine dose is: " + dogadose);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your formatting is a mess making it hard to read, can you format your code using your IDE?

Comment: I tidied up the formatting and removed some of the dead code using my IDE.  You don't even have to think about it if you use the right tool. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the only problem, but you should change

```
    double catcdose=usersCat.calcCarprofen(double weight);
    double catadose=usersCat.calcAcepromazine(double weight);
    double dogcdose=usersDog.calcCarprofen(double weight);
    double dogadose=usersDog.calcAcepromazine(double weight);
```

to

```
    double catcdose=usersCat.calcCarprofen(weight);
    double catadose=usersCat.calcAcepromazine(weight);
    double dogcdose=usersDog.calcCarprofen(weight);
    double dogadose=usersDog.calcAcepromazine(weight);
```

And if you intended to pass the `weight` variable to these methods, you must give it an initial value. Perhaps you meant to pass `startWeight` instead.

After another look, perhaps these methods don't need the weight argument at all, since you already pass the weight to the constructor and store it in a member of the instance.

Also make sure you get the method names right. I see `calcAzepromazine` in some places and `calcAcepromazine` in others.

Comment: I changed the main method to the following, so that when you input cat or dog it only does one or the other outputs. But for some reason the code completes after entering the weight of the animal, and doesn't output anything. why?

Comment: I posted the code as another answer to this questions

Answer (score 0):

You don't call methods this way

```
Pet.
    double catcdose=usersCat.calcCarprofen(double weight);
```

should probably be

```
double catcdose=usersCat.calcCarprofen(weight);
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the following error:
No suitable method found for calcCarprofen(no arguments)

Comment: @user10875 why don't you give it the argument it expects, just like I did in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

```
    public class Ch7Ex8 {
public void Ch7Ex8 () {

}

public static void main(String [] args) {


    double startWeight;
    String startKind;
    double weight=0;

    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Is this a cat or dog?: ");
        startKind=keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the pet's weight: ");
        startWeight= keyboard.nextDouble();

        if (startKind=="cat" || startKind=="Dog") {
            Pet usersPet=new Pet(startKind, startWeight);
            Cat usersCat= new Cat(startKind, startWeight);
            double catcdose=usersCat.calcCarprofen();
            double catadose=usersCat.calcAcepromazine();
            System.out.println("The total cat carprofen dose is: "+catcdose);
            System.out.println("The total cat acepromazine dose is: "+catadose);

        } else if (startKind=="dog" || startKind=="Dog") {
            Pet usersPet=new Pet(startKind, startWeight);
            Dog usersDog= new Dog(startKind, startWeight);
            double dogcdose=usersDog.calcCarprofen();
            double dogadose=usersDog.calcAcepromazine();
            System.out.println("The total dog carprofen dose is: "+dogcdose);
            System.out.println("The total dog acepromazine dose is: "+dogadose);
        }


}
```

}

Comment: use `equals` to compare Strings, not ==. And please don't post additional questions as answers.